# How to handle different plan options with Stripe?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using Laravel and Stripe. I have 5 different subscription plans in my app. Each plan has its own set of options, like

*Basic Plan*
 - max campaigns - 20
 - max emails - 100

*Pro Plan* 
 - max campaigns - 40
 - max emails - 200

etc.

How do I represent those options in my DB?

I use Laravel's cashier, it nicely handles subscriptions table, where it stores subscription name, stripe plan id, etc.

But I want later when user is about to create a campaign make a check if he can do this, i.e he has not reached campaigns limit according to his plan.

Sounds like I need another table like `plan_options` where I'd store all of this. My concern is how do I connect it to this subscriptions table? manually? right after user subscribed, do I have to find a subscirption name he picked up, find it in the plan_options table and connect them using the id? is it correct way to do this?

Comment: You can just have the `plan_options` table and a new field in the subscription table named `plan_id`. At the time of access or anytime the user tries to add a campaign - compare their current amount of campaigns with the plan's options (maximum).

Answer (score 2):

You can save `plan_options` into subscription plan metadata into Stripe. That way, everything stays at one place and there is no sync required.

[image]

You can access the metadata using the API as follows.

Example Request:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_ascfadfaeadsfadsfasdfasdfV");

\Stripe\Plan::retrieve("pro");
```

Example Response:

```
Stripe\Plan JSON: {
  "id": "pro",
  "object": "plan",
  "amount": 1000,
  "created": 1453123864,
  "currency": "usd",
  "interval": "month",
  "interval_count": 1,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
    "campaigns_limit": "40",
    "emails_limit": "200"
  },
  "name": "Pro Plan",
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "trial_period_days": 30
}
```

With many subscription plans in place, the centralized information would remove many complexities.

> PS: The Response has Strings and not numbers/integers in the JSON.

Comment: does this call the stripe api every single time you want to check said metadata, or is it stored in the laravel database?

Comment: You can cache this data somewhere if you do not want to make Stripe API calls that frequently. There are tradeoffs, storing this info in the payment plans' metadata, keeps all the related info at one place (one source of truth). Rare chance of getting data out of sync.